# I want to find a name of game

Tags: quest

I’m looking for Game in it there is two old mans in two islands throw objects form the island to hit each other by Catapult and when you start the game the game let you choose between the two old mans Plz if anyone remember The name of the Game Tell Me because I searched it for two years and i didn't find the game.